# How to include cursor movements in vim macros

Tags: vim, macros

Macros don't seem to take into account keystrokes. In this particular case I want to write a macro which comments out a line (in latex comments start with `%`). Here are the keystrokes I'm using:

<kbd>q</kbd> +
<kbd>a</kbd> + 
<kbd>0</kbd> + 
<kbd>w</kbd> + 
<kbd>i</kbd> +
<kbd>%</kbd> + 
<kbd>j</kbd> + 
<kbd>j</kbd> + 
<kbd>j</kbd> + 
<kbd>q</kbd>

Which assigns a macro to a, goes to the beginning of the line, enters insert mode, places a percent sign, exits insert mode, moves down a line, and ends the macro. I then use the macro like so

<kbd>@</kbd> + 
<kbd>a</kbd>

If I have 4 lines like so

```
1   In This life I have learned one thing █
2   It is pity incarnate of which I sing.
3   You have been told about the back of the crowd
4   And I repeat it, plenty loud.
```

using the macro three times causes this

```
1   %%%In This life I have learned one thing █
2   It is pity incarnate of which I sing.
3   You have been told about the back of the crowd
4   And I repeat it, plenty loud.
```

When what I want is this

```
1   %In This life I have learned one thing █
2   %It is pity incarnate of which I sing.
3   %You have been told about the back of the crowd
4   And I repeat it, plenty loud.
```

More specifically I want to be able to do 30 + <kbd>@</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to comment out 30 lines. How do I do this?

Comment: `jj` is remapped to escape? Use escape then. And instead of all of this use CTRL-V to blockwise select 30 start of lines, and then `I` (capital). See `:help v_b_I`

Comment: @Benoit I'm not familiar with any of that (except I believe ctrl + v is block selection mode). Could you place that as an answer

Comment: You could use one of the many automatic commenting plugins. My personal favorite is [tcomment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)

Comment: @DavidBrown thanks, I have never come across that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for :

```
:.,+30 s/^\s*/&%
```

Explanation:

- `.,+30` is a range spanning from current line to current line + 30 (hence spanning over 31 lines) (`:help range`)
- `s` is the substitution command (`:help :s`)
- `/` is the pattern delimiter
- `^\s*` is a pattern (`:help pattern`) that corresponds to any number of spaces at the beginning of a line
- `&` is a replacement special character that inserts the matched pattern

Other way:

```
ab©d (cursor on the c)
efgh
ijkl
```

Type <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>, `2j`, `I`, hello, <kbd>Esc</kbd> and you get:

```
abhellocd
efhellogh
ijhellokl
```

Comment: ummmm...for everything from the current line to the next 30 lines do word replace of...hat backslash ess and * (which I take means the begining of the line) and replace it with the and sign and the percent sign (which I take to be...something?)

Answer (score 3):

Nice answer by Benoit.

I think your macro should be

```
I%<Esc>j
```

After that it's only

```
30@a
```

If you shorten your macro to

```
I%<Esc>
```

you can visually select all the lines and do

```
:'<,'>norm @a
```

or work on a range like in Benoit's answer.

You can also skip the macro part and use VISUAL-BLOCK mode:

```
<C-v> " enter visual block mode
30G   " go to line 30
I%    " insert % at the beginning of selection
<Esc> " exit visual block mode
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [:normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal) command. What it does is execute it's argument as normal mode commands. It can also be given a range, so to insert a % in front of the next 30 lines you could enter `:.,+30 norm I%`. The `I` puts vim in Insert Mode with the cursor at the beginning of the current line. Since you're now in insert mode the `%` just inserts a `%` character.

Comment: Could you explain a little more as to what `I` does (for completeness, I personally know what it does...now that I googled it)?